# await not working in async promise node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, puppeteer

I have this code in node.js with puppeteer with Axios that makes POST request, get the response and uses that response in puppeteer.

```
card = axios
            .post('https://example.com/post', {
                email: emailVal,
                password: passwordVal
            })
            .then(async (res) => {
                console.log(`STATUS CODE: ${res.data.statusCode}`)
                let cardName = res.data.cardholder.name.split(" ")[0];
                let cardLastname = res.data.cardholder.name.split(" ")[1];
                let cardAddress = res.data.cardholder.billing.address.line1;
                await page.waitFor(1000);
                console.log('REDIRECTED TO ADDRESS')
                await page.goto('https://example.com/address');
                //await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }); // Wait for page to finish loading
                await page.waitFor(10000);
                await Promise.all([
                    await page.evaluate(()=>document.querySelector('#mobile-container > div > div > form > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.mex-add-new-payment-container.mt9-sm.flx-jc-md-fe.u-full-width.ta-sm-c.pt6-sm.pb6-sm.d-sm-flx.flx-jc-sm-c > div.flx-jc-md-fe.d-sm-h.d-md-flx.flx-jc-sm-c > button').click())
                ]);
                
                console.log("OPENED ADDRESS POPUP")
                await page.waitFor(10000);

                const typeFirstName = await page.$('#givenName');
                await typeFirstName.click({ clickCount: 3 })
                await page.type('#givenName', cardName);
                console.log('CARD NAME: ' + cardName)

                console.log('CARD ADDRESS: ' + cardAddress)

          

             

                await page.waitFor(5000);
                const saveCard = await page.$('#modal-root > div > div > div > div > section > div.css-1h4dz32.e1eje3q30 > div > div > button');
                await saveCard.click({ clickCount: 1 })
                console.log('CLICKED SAVE')
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error)
            });
```

and this part of the code in .then(async (res) gets ignored (like it does not exist)

```
console.log(`STATUS CODE: ${res.data.statusCode}`)
                let cardName = res.data.cardholder.name.split(" ")[0];
                let cardLastname = res.data.cardholder.name.split(" ")[1];
                let cardAddress = res.data.cardholder.billing.address.line1;
                await page.waitFor(1000);
                console.log('REDIRECTED TO ADDRESS')
                await page.goto('https://example.com/address');
                //await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }); // Wait for page to finish loading
                await page.waitFor(10000);
                await Promise.all([
                    await page.evaluate(()=>document.querySelector('#mobile-container > div > div > form > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.mex-add-new-payment-container.mt9-sm.flx-jc-md-fe.u-full-width.ta-sm-c.pt6-sm.pb6-sm.d-sm-flx.flx-jc-sm-c > div.flx-jc-md-fe.d-sm-h.d-md-flx.flx-jc-sm-c > button').click())
                ]);
                
                console.log("OPENED ADDRESS POPUP")
                await page.waitFor(10000);

                const typeFirstName = await page.$('#givenName');
                await typeFirstName.click({ clickCount: 3 })
                await page.type('#givenName', cardName);
                console.log('CARD NAME: ' + cardName)

                console.log('CARD ADDRESS: ' + cardAddress)

          

             

                await page.waitFor(5000);
                const saveCard = await page.$('#modal-root > div > div > div > div > section > div.css-1h4dz32.e1eje3q30 > div > div > button');
                await saveCard.click({ clickCount: 1 })
                console.log('CLICKED SAVE')
```

Do you know what am I doing wrong? I can not remove async before the then function, so I got stuck at this point.

Comment: It is better not to mix up 'async await' with '.then' syntax. You should decide which one you prefer and refactor this.

Comment: @KonstantinSamarin if I remove async, awaits give an error, but I HAVE to use puppeteer commands because I use Axios responses to populate the inputs. I think puppeteer code needs await, that is why I'm confused.

Comment: Why are you using async-awaits with Promises ? That's just bad

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan because I use puppeteer in 'then'. The problem is, this code charges one dollar every time I launch it, thus I can not test if it works without async and await(

Comment: @A.Bokizh You should switch to using either async-await or promises, either way async await is just a cool syntax for promises, so if you can code something with Promises(.then.catch) then you can do the same with async-await.